# communication between client and server through socket using two different application

Tags: android

***Hi,
I want to create the two different applications one for server side which runs on computer and the other one is client side which runs on android tablet.Both the applications sends and receive data through socket, or if any other communication method is available is also acceptable.
Please help.
Thanks.***

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with the socket programming . Best way is to use restful web services. the following link is use full for restful webserices http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: It's not simple java application. I want to implement this in my android application.Is it possible?

Comment: yes. for that android only i suggested restful web services. i already worked on that.

Comment: have find some thing regarding your issue?

Comment: @Srikanth Can you please explain why this is not possible ?